# Switching 3.3V with a Raspberry Pi gpio pin

Tags: transistors, resistors, raspberry-pi, infrared, camera

I recently bought an IR Camera for my Raspberry Pi, something like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/kuman-Raspberry-Camera-Module-Supports/dp/B01ICLLOZ8/ref=mp_s_a_1_17?crid=M3FSU2COLT5W&keywords=ir+raspberry+pi+camera&qid=1553193365&s=gateway&sprefix=ir+rasp&sr=8-17](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01ICLLOZ8)

The only problem with the camera is the temperature of the IR leds which get way to high over time. Because I need these leds only one or two times in an hour I want to turn off those leds. My idea is to use a transistor which is switched by an gpio pin of a raspberry pi. But since I'm an amateur in using transistor I don't know which transistor and resistors to use. Any help?

The leds are powered by the camera with 3,3V and I measured about 0,28A at full brightness per led.

Comment: Do you have a schematic for the IR camera module?  Depending on how those LEDs are connected (one side is grounded/common and you can interrupt that) you can probably get away with just a logic-level MOSFET.

Comment: @evildemonic I haven't found a specific schematic but I can tell that the led is only connected via a positive and negative contact with the camera body. So yeah, should be ground and Vin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a MOSFET to control power through the LEDs like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNQKYV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Simply interrupt the connection between the LEDs and ground and insert an N-MOSFET.  Source to ground, drain to the LED, and the gate to your I/O pin.

You will need to make sure it is a 'logic level' MOSFET to ensure that it is fully on when supplied 3.3V.

A high signal on the I/O will turn the LEDs on, and a low level will turn them off.

Comment: Yeah that should work, I ordered some logic level mosfets online. They should arrive Monday. Gonna try it then. Thanks!